# How to manage windows logons from windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I have to create a windows service which is triggering multiple event. If some event fired the pc need to login the user. (Username / password is available in the central db)

Eg.: NFC-tag / pendrive detected check user id if exists in the db login the specified user.

Comment: @EugenePodskal: not a duplicate; triggering a logon is not the same thing as impersonation.

Comment: In Windows, the software you're trying to write is called a *credential provider*, software that modifies the way the logon screen works.  The documentation isn't very good, you might want to consider using a third-party library such as the one at http://pgina.org/ (which I've never used but have heard good things about).

Comment: @HarryJohnston Probably you are right and I have misread the question. I revoke my close vote.